How to disable auto play when connecting bluetooth or opening my laptop
When I open my laptop (i.e., the screen) or plug-in a bluetooth earbuds Ubuntu starts playing music/audio immediately (whatever is active, like YouTube, Videoplayer app or internet radio page, that is open and was stopped or was not playing audio before). How to disable?
